# What is a VM image offer with regards to a VM image ? In other words, what is the difference between `az vm image list` and `az vm image list-offers`?

Tags: azure

The only apparent difference between the `az vm image list` and `az vm image list-offers` commands is that the `--publisher` and `--location` options are required for `list-offers`, but they are also available options to the `list` subcommand. Furthermore, they give different results for the same parameters.

Can you explain what microsoft means by "vm image **offers**" compared to normal vm images ?

Comment: I assume you mean az vm image list and az vm image list-offers? az vm list, just lists virtual machines.

Comment: @SamCogan Yes I'm sorry, that's what I meant. I updated my post to correct this.